# JQuery ticker playing up by slowing and stopping then starting again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've implemented a JQuery Ticker from http://jonmifsud.com/open-source/jquery/jquery-webticker/ and it seems to be playing up on iPad.

What happens is after a few seconds the grey bar `.tickercontainer` moves along to the left, the text stops moving, and then the grey bar appears and the text continues to move again.

In the example it runs smoothly, however, on mine it doesn't even though I've implemented it in the exact same way just with a background colour. The slowing down and speeding up of text issue occurs also on Desktop, just the background colour remains there as it should.

**Edit:** It could have something to do with the `ul`'s `tansition-duration`? It keeps changing as you can now see in console: 6150 - twitter-feed.js (line 89), 13225 - twitter-feed.js (line 89), 9986.25 -  twitter-feed.js (line 89). As it divides by 1000 it basically transitions for between 6.15 to 13.225 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I've resolved it. I have had to use:

```
ul.newsticker { 
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```